# clj repl overwrites output

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I start the repl with `cjl` and get the prompt

```
Clojure 1.11.1
user=>
```

At the user prompt I enter `(+ 1 2 3)` and hit return. The output is this:

```
user=> (+ 1 2 (+ 1 2 3)
6
```

I think the operation I entered is being overwritten.

I'm in i3 window manager but, when I quit back to the OS console, it does the same thing. How can I fix that.

If it matters, I'm on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely due to a known issue with `rlwrap` (which `clj` uses to wrap the `clojure` script for interactive use).

If you create `.inputrc` file in your home directory with the following contents, it should solve the problem:

```
$if clojure
    set enable-bracketed-paste off
$endif
```